# key count ruby having splitted lines by commas and =>

Tags: ruby, mapreduce, reduce, word-count

having an input file like this being combinedbooks and booklist arrays: 
`combinedbooks. << (booklist.combination(2).map { |i| [i.join("|") , 1]}`)

Generates this as input:

```
0000A|0000B
1
0000A|0000C
1
0000B|0000C
1
0000A|0000B
1
0000A|0000C
1
0000B|0000C
1
0000A|0000B
1
0000A|0000D
1
0000B|0000D
1
```

I want to make a counter that counts the number of times each pair appears

The code I have written is as follows:

```
STDIN.each do |line|
     (key, value) = line.split(/\t/)
        if prev_key != nil && prev_key != key
            puts prev_key + "\t" + init_val.to_s
            prev_key = key
            init_val = 1
        elsif prev_key == nil
            prev_key = key
        elsif prev_key == key
            init_val = init_val + value.to_i
        end
    end
end

puts prev_key + "\t" + init_val.to_s
```

Of course it doesnt work, as im seprarting by tab but at the same time my key value pairs are separated also by tab. I dont know how to change the input file

The output I would like to get is the following:

```
     ["0000A|0000B"]    3
     ["0000A|0000C"]    2
     ["0000B|0000C"]    2
     ["0000A|0000D"]    1
     ["0000B|0000D"]    1
```

Comment: you showed the output you're getting - what is the output you'd *like* to get?

Comment: You show the "input" as three hashes. You may wish to write that as an array of three hashes and give it a name, e.g. `arr = {...}, {...}, {...}]`.

Comment: `STDIN.each` - are you parsing a Ruby script?

Comment: @CarySwoveland as u suggested I created an array with all the input data and I deleted my hash because actually it is not needed.

Comment: What is the `1` for in the .map line ?

Comment: @Anthony it is supposed to be the value to the key